# Remove raised effect in blackberry objectchoicefield and buttonfield

Tags: blackberry

I am trying to achieve a flat look for blackberry controls, namely objectchoicefield and buttonfield.

The following code does not seem to do the trick. (The width setting does work, but not the border setting.)

```
public static ObjectChoiceField GetDropdownList(String label, String[] data)
{
    ObjectChoiceField ocf = new ObjectChoiceField(null, data, 0, Field.FIELD_LEFT);

    ocf.setBorder(BorderFactory.createSimpleBorder(new XYEdges(0,0,0,0)));
    ocf.setMinimalWidth(Display.getWidth()-61);

    return ocf;
}
```

I get the same appearance with or without the setBorder statement. Basically I do not want any 3D look or shadow or shine or rounded corners.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not do **everything** you want, but you can try looking [at this custom ObjectChoiceField](http://www.enscand.com/roller/enscand/entry/custom_fancy_er_choicefield_for) that I built for OS 4.6 and *lower* devices.  I wanted to *add* a glossy, 3D look, but you could change the custom `paint()` code I used to make a simpler, flatter look.

Taking my example, changing the rounded corner radius to 1, and removing the call to `super.paint(g)` gives something like this:

```java
public class CustomChoiceField extends ObjectChoiceField {

   private int _bgWidth = 0;
   private int _bgHeight = 0;
   private int _numChoices = 0;
   private boolean _hasFocus = false;
   private static final int HIGHLIGHT_COLOR = 0xFF185AB5;  // blue-ish
   private static final int RADIUS = 1;    // rounded corner radius in pixels
   private static final int DFLT_PADDING = 20;

   public CustomChoiceField(Object[] choices, int initialIndex) {
      super("", choices, initialIndex);
      _numChoices = choices.length;
   }

   public int getPreferredHeight() {
      return _bgHeight;
   }

   public int getPreferredWidth() {
      return _bgWidth;
   }

   protected void layout(int width, int height) {
      if (_bgWidth == 0 || _bgHeight == 0) {
         if (height <= Display.getHeight()) {
            // probably using custom Manager to specify size
            _bgWidth = width;
            _bgHeight = height;
         } else {
            // use default sizing
            _bgHeight = DFLT_PADDING + getHeightOfChoices();
            for (int i = 0; i < _numChoices; i++) {
               _bgWidth = Math.max(_bgWidth, DFLT_PADDING + getWidthOfChoice(i));
            }
         }
      }

      super.layout(_bgWidth, _bgHeight);
      super.setExtent(_bgWidth, _bgHeight);
   }   

   protected void applyTheme(Graphics arg0, boolean arg1) {
      // do nothing
   }

   protected void drawFocus(Graphics g, boolean on) {
      // do nothing .. handled manually in paint(g)
   }

   protected void onFocus(int direction) {
      _hasFocus = true;
      super.onFocus(direction);
      invalidate();
   }

   protected void onUnfocus() {
      _hasFocus = false;
      super.onUnfocus();
      invalidate();  // required to clear focus
   }

   protected void paint(Graphics g) {
      int oldColor = g.getColor();

      // field color depends on whether we have focus or not
      int bgColor = (_hasFocus) ? HIGHLIGHT_COLOR : Color.BLACK;
      // when the field has focus, we make it a little less transparent
      int alpha = (_hasFocus) ? 0xDD : 0xBB;
      g.setColor(bgColor);
      g.setGlobalAlpha(alpha);
      g.fillRoundRect(0, 0, _bgWidth, _bgHeight, RADIUS, RADIUS);

      // draw a plain white line as a border
      g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
      g.setGlobalAlpha(0xFF);
      g.drawRoundRect(0, 0, _bgWidth, _bgHeight, RADIUS, RADIUS);

      // draw the currently selected choice's text (also in white)
      String text = (String)getChoice(getSelectedIndex());
      int y = (_bgHeight - getFont().getHeight()) / 2;
      g.drawText(text, 0, y, DrawStyle.HCENTER | DrawStyle.TOP, _bgWidth);
      g.setColor(oldColor);
   }
}
```

And you use the `CustomChoiceField` like this:

```java
   private ObjectChoiceField[] ocf = new ObjectChoiceField[3];

   public ObjectChoiceScreen() {
      super(MainScreen.VERTICAL_SCROLL | MainScreen.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR);
      Object[] choices1 = new Object[] { "one", "two", "three" };
      ocf[0] = new CustomChoiceField(choices1, 0);
      Object[] choices2 = new Object[] { "ichi", "ni", "san" };
      ocf[1] = new CustomChoiceField(choices2, 0);
      Object[] choices3 = new Object[] { "uno", "dos", "tres" };
      ocf[2] = new CustomChoiceField(choices3, 0);
      for (int i = 0; i < ocf.length; i++) {
         ocf[i].setMargin(new XYEdges(10, 10, 10, 10));
      }
      getMainManager().addAll(ocf);
```

This isn't production code, so you'll need to test it yourself.  For example, it doesn't handle changing the choices with `setChoices()`.  But, it's a start, and will get you something like this:

[image]

You'll notice the difference in color between the first two object choice fields, and the bottom one, which is focused.

My code has the same popup for selecting choices as the normal `ObjectChoiceField`.  So, you still may get rounded corners that way.  In my case, I didn't need to change that look and feel, so I'm not sure how you might change that, too.

Comment: Thanks Nate. I just took the override paint part and it works well.  The focus-highlight color seems to have some issues maybe because I didn't take the rest of the code.

Comment: @RazaAli, you're welcome.  Yes, the focus painting does require the rest of the code, outside of just `paint()`.  But, if you want your focus highlighting to look different, you certainly don't need to use it.  If you found the answer useful, please consider upvoting, as well as accepting the answer (which you did).  Thanks!

Comment: Actually the issue I am facing is that the first time it focuses on the choice control, it highlights the left half of it only. When I change focus and return to the control, it highlights properly. I haven't got a chance to dig into this yet.

Comment: Ok, but like I said, if you want my code to perform focus handling for you, you need the whole class, not just the `paint()` method.  In my example, the focus and unfocus colors are controlled by this line: `int bgColor = (_hasFocus) ? HIGHLIGHT_COLOR : Color.BLACK;`.  `_hasFocus` is set by overriding the `onFocus()` and `onUnfocus()` methods as I've done.  Also, the painted background won't be the right **size** without the code in `layout()`.