# How to change the color of an objectchoicefield title

Tags: java, blackberry, eclipse-plugin

Hi is there a way to rewrite paint as i did with this LabelField to change just the title color of my ObjectChoiceField .

```
LabelField f = new LabelField("Title "){
                    protected void paint(Graphics g) {
                          g.setColor(Color.RED); 
                          super.paint(g);
                      }
                };
```

I want to change the font color of "title" :

```
final String[] options={"1","2","3"};
final ObjectChoiceField ocf=new ObjectChoiceField("Title",options);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "title"? Are you referring to the "label" that sits **next** to the field, or the strings displayed for the different *choices* themselves?

Comment: @Nate Hello The label that sits next to the field. How can i rewrite the properties for that "label" in ObjectChoiceField. When i said title color i ment the font color of the string that is next of your posible choices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do it almost exactly as it's done for `LabelField`.  You would override `paint()` and make a call to `Graphics#setColor()`:

```
   public class CustomColorChoiceField extends ObjectChoiceField {

      public CustomColorChoiceField(String label, Object[] choices, int initialIndex) {
         super("title", choices, initialIndex);
      }

      protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
         int oldColor = graphics.getColor();
         graphics.setColor(Color.GREEN);
         super.paint(graphics);
         graphics.setColor(oldColor);
      }
   }
```

and then add it to a screen the normal way:

```
  add(new CustomColorChoiceField("title", choices1, 0));
```

**Note:** I actually usually *don't* use `ObjectChoiceField` this way.  I almost always wind up passing in `""` (the empty string) as the title.  If I do want something like the title/label, I will usually create a `LabelField` and then place it exactly where I want it.   So, if you do it that way, you don't need to create your own `ObjectChoiceField` subclass at all.  Just pass an empty string into the choice field as the title/label, and then create a colored `LabelField` as you've shown in your question.

If you're interested in changing the colors, or other properties of the choices themselves (not the title/label), then [see this recent Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19111374/119114), or [check out a blog post I wrote on this a long time ago](http://www.enscand.com/roller/enscand/entry/custom_fancy_er_choicefield_for).

Comment: Thank you @Nate i actually did what you say about letting another label to control my objectchoicefield "Tittle" and let the string label empty , so i can easily change its color and font style. I just put a gridfield with 1 row and 2 columns: 1 column has the labelfield with the title and the second one an objectchoicefield with an empty string label.